# Naming N sublists in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

This was my first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73574049/naming-sublists-in-r/73574072#73574072) for naming a list that contained lists that contained a dataframe:

Now my list contains even more lists, but at the end a dataframe:

[image]

So for every list level, I do have a vector, for the names these are the vectors:

```
spaces = 5;
low_mu0 = 0.005; high_mu0 = 0.01;
low_sigma_e = 0.0001; high_sigma_e = 0.001;
low_tau0 = 10; high_tau0 = 20;
low_phi1 = 0.5; high_phi1 = 2;
low_phi2 = -0.5; high_phi2 = 0.5;
low_sigma_n = 0.0001; high_sigma_n = 0.001;
low_c0 = -0.1; high_c0 = 0.1;
low_c1 = -0.1; high_c1 = 0.1


range_mu0 <- seq(low_mu0, high_mu0, length.out = spaces)
range_sigma_e <- seq(low_sigma_e, high_sigma_e, length.out = spaces)
range_tau0 <- seq(low_tau0, high_tau0, length.out = spaces)
range_phi1 <- seq(low_phi1, high_phi1, length.out = spaces)
range_phi2 <- seq(low_phi2, high_phi2, length.out = spaces)
range_sigma_n <- seq(low_sigma_n, high_sigma_n, length.out = spaces)
range_c0 <- seq(low_c0, high_c0, length.out = spaces)
range_c1 <- seq(low_c1, high_c1, length.out = spaces)
```

For naming each level I tried this:

```
a2 <- setNames(lapply(a, function(x) 
  setNames(x, nm = paste("mu =", range_mu0))),
  setNames(x, paste("sigma_e =", range_sigma_e)),
  setNames(x, paste("tau =", range_tau0)),
  setNames(x, paste("phi1 =", range_phi1)),
  setNames(x, paste("phi2 =", range_phi2)),
  setNames(x, paste("sigma_n =", range_sigma_n)),
  setNames(x, paste("c0 =", range_c0)),
  paste("c1 =", range_c1))
```

But gives me an error, is there any way to have a general naming version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73574049/naming-sublists-in-r/73574072#73574072) question?

Thanks in advance!

### data

the data is kinda massive, so I put it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u-V8PGk_g7fI3aYSqBeEs9-6DrPVblNh/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why don't you reduce this list to a minimal workable example. These things can be generalized but I am having a hard time understanding the structure of your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this recursively. I'm using the two-level list from your previous question but it works for deeper lists as well.

```r
set_names <- function(lst, level.names) {
  
  if (length(level.names) > 0) {
    
    names(lst) <- paste(names(level.names)[1], '=', level.names[[1]])
    lapply(lst, set_names, level.names[-1])
    
  } else { # deepest level
    
    lst
  }
}

# store level names in a list
lev.names <- list('y0'=seq(10, 20, length.out=3),
                  'sigma_e'=seq(0, 1, length.out=3))
lst <- set_names(lst, lev.names)
```

```r
sapply(lst, names)
#      y0 = 10         y0 = 15         y0 = 20        
# [1,] "sigma_e = 0"   "sigma_e = 0"   "sigma_e = 0"  
# [2,] "sigma_e = 0.5" "sigma_e = 0.5" "sigma_e = 0.5"
# [3,] "sigma_e = 1"   "sigma_e = 1"   "sigma_e = 1"
```

Data:

```r
lst <- list(list(structure(list(period = 1:10, y = c(NA, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)), structure(list(period = 1:10, y = c(NA, 10, 10.7793541570746, 
10.8146083527869, 10.8792522203673, 11.736784713809, 11.9672428168036, 
11.3347121995003, 10.9912857735535, 10.7684547885036)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)), structure(list(period = 1:10, y = c(NA, 10, 11.5587083141491, 
11.6292167055737, 11.7585044407346, 13.4735694276179, 13.9344856336071, 
12.6694243990006, 11.9825715471071, 11.5369095770071)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))), list(structure(list(period = 1:10, y = c(NA, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)), structure(list(period = 1:10, y = c(NA, 15, 15.7793541570746, 
15.8146083527869, 15.8792522203673, 16.736784713809, 16.9672428168036, 
16.3347121995003, 15.9912857735535, 15.7684547885036)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)), structure(list(period = 1:10, y = c(NA, 15, 16.5587083141491, 
16.6292167055737, 16.7585044407346, 18.4735694276179, 18.9344856336071, 
17.6694243990006, 16.9825715471071, 16.5369095770071)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))), list(structure(list(period = 1:10, y = c(NA, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)), structure(list(period = 1:10, y = c(NA, 20, 20.7793541570746, 
20.8146083527868, 20.8792522203673, 21.736784713809, 21.9672428168036, 
21.3347121995003, 20.9912857735535, 20.7684547885036)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)), structure(list(period = 1:10, y = c(NA, 20, 21.5587083141491, 
21.6292167055737, 21.7585044407346, 23.4735694276179, 23.9344856336071, 
22.6694243990006, 21.9825715471071, 21.5369095770071)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))))
```

Answer (score 1):

With the original data, we need a nested `lapply` with `setNames`

```
a2 <- setNames(lapply(a, function(x1) 
        setNames(lapply(x1, function(x2) 
           setNames(lapply(x2, function(x3)
             setNames(lapply(x3, function(x4)
               setNames(lapply(x4, function(x5)
                 setNames(lapply(x5, function(x6)
                   setNames(lapply(x6, function(x7)
                     setNames(x7, paste("c1 =", range_c1))
                     ), paste("c0 =", range_c0))
                   
                   
                   ), paste("sigma_n =", range_sigma_n))
                 
               ), paste("phi2 =", range_phi2))
             ), paste("phi1 =", range_phi1))
          
          
          ), paste("tau =", range_tau0))
        ),  paste("sigma_e =", range_sigma_e))
     ), paste("mu =", range_mu0))
```

-output

[image]